# Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes

Tags: php, sql-delete, delete-record

I am trying to figure out how I can delete multiple records using check boxes. I have a table on my page that gets the data from the database. The first column for each row has a check box that looks like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value='.$row['UserId'].' class="checkbox" />
```

My code looks like the following:

```
<?php
// get required includes
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'connections/mysql.php');
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'admin/controls/users_az/error_messages.php');

// declare variables
$msg = '';

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// DELETE SELECTED USERS
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
if(isset($_POST['btnDeleteSelected']) && isset($_POST['checked']))
{
$checked = array_map(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['checked']));
$list = "'" . implode("','", $checked) . "'";

$delete_selected = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM users WHERE UserId IN ($list)")
or die($dataaccess_error);

if($delete_selected)
{
    $msg = mysqli_affected_rows($delete_selected).' '.$msg_success;
}
}
elseif(isset($_POST['btnDeleteSelected']) && !isset($_POST['checked']))
{
$msg = $msg_error;
}
?>
```

**Problem:** Naturally this does not work. This is the first time I am attempting to do this.

**Question:** Am I on the right path with this? How do I need to modify this to make it work?

Comment: Can you put up a complete SQL string, after you've attempted to add the IDs?

Comment: And yes, you can do it this way.  You should escape your IDs first, though, using `mysql_real_escape_string()`; otherwise, someone could set the value of a checkbox to something nasty (sql injection).

Comment: Define does not work. Are there any errors?

Comment: 'This does not work' is vague... do you get any error message? You should try the generated SQL string in your mysql client to check its validity.

Comment: @mway: btw, its pointless to run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on a INT value, because the value is first being converted to INT it doesn't need to be sanitized with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, infact it might just cause trouble.

Comment: "Naturally this does not work." What does "this does not work" mean? And why is it "naturally"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will yield an error:

```
$checked = array_map(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['checked']));
```

Because `array_map` wants a callback as the first, and an array as the second argument. The rest of the setup is pretty good, but as `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs a connection, array_map or array_walk aren't that convenient, you might try a normal `foreach` loop. Alternatively, if the id's are always integers:

```
$checked = array_map('intval',$_POST['checked']);
```

... and drop the quotes around the values in the implode statement (try to feed mysql integers for integer columns, strings for other (char/date/blob/text) columns).

Comment: It seems to work now but I still get the following error: Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\MyCMS\admin\controls\users_az\delete_selected.php on line 22

Comment: Aha, next issue: [`mysqli_query`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query) will return `true` for successful `DELETE` queries. You don't feed `mysqli_affected_rows` the result of the query, you give it the connection (`mysqli_affected_rows($conn);`)

Answer (score 0):

Just check that every element of your array is an integer (with ctype_digit()) for instance, and then you can use implode without quotes, like this:

```
$list = implode(", ", $checked);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\MyCMS\admin\controls\users_az\delete_selected.php on line 14

Warning: array_map() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\MyCMS\admin\controls\users_az\delete_selected.php on line 14

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\MyCMS\admin\controls\users_az\delete_selected.php on line 16

Comment: Yes your array_map() statement is not correct : it should have 2 parameters instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP >= 5.3 you can use an anonymous function:

```
$checked = array_map(function($s) use ($conn) { return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $s); }, $_POST['checked']);
```

Otherwise you could either callback to a user defined function:

```
$checked = array_map('myescape', $_POST['checked']);
function myescape($s)
{
    global $conn;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $s);
}
```

or just manually loop.

Comment: Super! I really like the anonymous function. It is very elegant and sophisticated. I wish I could understand the curly brackets in the syntax.

Comment: The curly braces are simply encapsulating the function's definition (just as you would with any other user defined function).